# Tab order in QDialog always moving to QTableWidget last

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I have a QDialog that contains a bunch of fields, buttons and a custom widget that inherits QTableWidget somewhere in the middle. I have the tab order set up the way I want it and it works fine, *but only the first time though.* After focusing on the last widget in the tab order and pressing tab again *the focus goes back to the custom QTableWidget!* It doesn't go back to number 1 in the tab order!

I have tried changing the tab order to something else and I still get the same result. After tabbing out of the last widget the focus goes to the table (which is #26 out of 38 in the tab order) instead of the first field.

I have tried setting "NoFocus" on the main QDialog and the custom table widget itself. I am also not using setTabOrder() anywhere on the QDialog or on my table widget.

What could be going on?